# What is the name/type for this soldering iron tip?

Tags: soldering

I got a old soldering iron, I'm trying to find the replacement tip but I don't know what to search for. When I search soldering iron tip it only show the hakko style tips. Can someone help me identify this tip?

[image]

Comment: (1) Could you add some scale reference (diameter at the thickest place, perhaps)?  (2) There is some writing around the barrel.  It could be the part number.  Look it up.  (3) Be morally prepared that you will not find the exotic replacement tips.  When buying a soldering iron, always check the availability and price of the tips.

Comment: Do you have the make or model name/number of the soldering iron itself, that would surely help.

Comment: I name thee *Carl*

Comment: Do a image search on google images.

Comment: @Nick: the tip is the same size as the regular hakko style tip except the tip is cutted in half

Comment: @Nedd the manufacture is ungar, i'm not sure of the model number I have to look it up once I get home

Comment: @OzzieSpin  I tried that already, mostly I got white pen in return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of these available from an Ebay seller:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Ungar-Soldering-Iron-Tips-9015-X2-/281868809328

Says they are for Ungar Models 9911, 9911as, 9370, 9380 and UTC 200 series Irons.

Here is another reference:

http://www.waveroomplus.com/Vanier-Soldering-Tip-U610--Equivalent-To-WellerUngar-9015_p_2934.html

Comment: I was hoping to get the tip form factor type name, but this will do. Thanks!